# java.lang.IllegalAccessException: can not access a member of class java.util.Collections$UnmodifiableCollection with modifiers "public"

Tags: jsf-2, el

I have classes `PrimitiveProperty` and `ComplexProperty` and the interface `Property`. I want to create an implementation of Property which enforces an empty unmodifiable Set of `Property` instances as return value of `Property.getProperties`, e.g.

```
public interface Property {
    Set<Property> getProperties();
}

public class ComplexProperty implements Property {
    private Set<Property> properties; 
    //getter overrides the interface method
}

public class PrimitiveProperty implements Property {
    private final static Set<Property> EMPTY_PROPS = Collections.unmodifiableSet(new HashSet<Property>(1));

    @Override
    public Set<Property> getProperties() {
        return EMPTY_PROPS;
    }
}
```

With Glassfish 4.0 and I'm getting

> java.lang.IllegalAccessException: Class javax.el.ELUtil can not access a member of class java.util.Collections$UnmodifiableCollection with modifiers "public"

when I access the property in the `leaf` attribute of a Richfaces `tree`, e.g.

```
<r:tree id="aTree" 
        toggleType="ajax" var="item" >
  <r:treeModelRecursiveAdaptor roots="#{aCtrl.roots}" 
                               nodes="#{item.properties}" leaf="#{item.properties.isEmpty()}">
    <r:treeNode>
      #{item.name}
    </r:treeNode>
    <r:treeModelAdaptor nodes="#{item.properties}" leaf="#{item.properties.isEmpty()}"/>
  </r:treeModelRecursiveAdaptor>
</r:tree>
```

The issue disappears if I make the `EMPTY_PROPS` constant modifiable (by assigning an instance of `HashSet` instead of the return value of `Collections.unmodifiableSet`) which is not my intention.

Is it possible to achieve what I want to do? Do I have to invent or use an implementation of what `Collections$UnmodifiableCollection` ('s subclasses) do(es) which is compatible with the JSF access needs?

Comment: You forgot to show how you're accessing it (in the view side).

Comment: I've used the `Arrays#asList` utility, which returns an unmodifiable `List` quite frequently, with no problem. Don't know why you have that error for the `Set`.

Comment: The clue is in the way how he's accessing it.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Here is the problem:

```
leaf="#{item.properties.isEmpty()}"
```

You're attempting to invoke a method directly on the `UnmodifiableSet` instance. Although it implements `Collection`, which is `public`, the `UnmodifiableSet` implementation itself, where EL (read: Reflection API) is trying to find the method on the class, is *not* `public`.

Exactly this problem is reproducible in plain Java (a `main()` method) as follows:

```
Set<Object> set = Collections.unmodifiableSet(new HashSet<>());
for (Method method : set.getClass().getMethods()) {
    if ("isEmpty".equals(method.getName())) {
        method.invoke(set); // IllegalAccessException.
    }
}
```

This is essentially a bug in the EL implementation used.

You'd better just use EL's own `empty` operator:

```
leaf="#{empty item.properties}"
```

Comment: ... and once more, a JSF abstraction turns out to leak implementation details: to use EL, one should not have to be aware of the specifics of how it interacts with the Reflection API (a public method implemented in a private class can be invoked through reflection by using `setAccessible(true)` or through the method object of the public super type that declared the method).

Comment: It's just a bug in EL impl used.

Comment: @BalusC What would be an approprieate El implementation - I experimented with different versions of `javax.el:el-api` and `org.glassfish.web:el-impl` (I'm using and deploying to glassfish)[http://ocpsoft.org/java/jsf2-java/jsf2-how-to-add-the-magic-of-el-el2-to-jsf/] and combinations of them, but I guess I don't know what I'm doing nor where to find infos.

Comment: Apache's EL implementation (as used in my Tomcat 7.0.55) doesn't expose this bug. But I wouldn't worry much about this. Just use the `empty` operator. There it is for.

Comment: Is it a bug in EL or in Java? How would you modify your java code above so that is doesn't throw the exception?

Comment: @Maurice: From the answer: *"This is essentially a bug in the EL implementation used"* and *"You'd better just use EL's own `empty` operator"*.

Comment: @BalusC OK. Now I've had the same problem in a different context (not with EL). Again, How would you modify your java code above so that is doesn't throw the exception? If I call `set.isEmpty()` (or `set.size()`) in Java, it works without problem. How can we make if work with reflection?

Comment: @BalusC (I've tryed `method.setAccessible(true);`, it doesn't work)

Comment: @Maurice: Oh? Just do `instanceof Collection` or `instanceof Iterable` (depending on your coverage) and then simply downcast and perform `Collection#isEmpty()` or `Iterator#hasNext()` rather than doing reflection trickery.

Comment: @BalusC There are times when you need "reflection trickery". Thanks anyway.

Comment: @Maurice: I have yet to find a real world use case where `instanceof` and downcast (or inherently `Class#isAssignableFrom()` or `Class#isInstance()` followed by `Class#cast()`) is impossible and therefore "reflection trickery" is required.

Comment: @BalusC I guess your "real world" doesn't include say, an implementation of "EL".

Comment: @Maurice: even in EL the base is readily available in evaluation context. Therefore, *"This is essentially a bug in the EL implementation used"* and *"You'd better just use EL's own `empty` operator"*.